# How to create this query properly?

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code to `WP_Query`. But I am not much good in PHP and WordPress, so please help me to solve this.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'job', 
    (isset($gender)) ? 
        ('meta_key'  => 'gender',
        'meta_value'     => $gender)
    : '');
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But its showing this error and I am not sure, how to format it.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in XXX
```

How can I format it to make array like this.

```
$args= array( 'post_type' => 'job',
              'meta_key' => 'gender',
              'meta_value'  => $gender
       );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php 
    $args = array('post_type' => 'job');
    if(isset($gender)){
        $args['meta_key'] = 'gender';
        $args['meta_value'] = $gender;
    }
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
```